# input height:23px makes <p> height:28px :(

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" id="SQL:79" name="SQL" value="79" maxlength="300">
    <label for="SQL:79">Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express - 64 bit</label>
</p>
```

relevant CSS:

```
p {
   line-height:23px; 
   vertical-align:top;
   margin:0 0 8px 0;
   padding:0;
   clear:both
}
input {
   margin:0 5px 0 0; 
   padding:0; 
   height:23px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
   border:none; 
   background:none;
   vertical-align:text-bottom
}
label {
   vertical-align:top
}
```

My input and label are exact 23px high, however the `<p>` is 28px :(

When I remove vertical-align from the input, the `<p>` reduces to 25px; but still not the desired 23px!

**I have changed the vertical-align on the input[type=radio] from text-bottom to plain bottom/top; this makes the parent p exactly 23px :)**
PS: this line of code comes from the HTML5 boilerplate reset, so be aware!

Comment: maybe some padding overrides your styles

Comment: there is no padding on either p, input or label

Comment: Wait, margin is on right, not bottom. :D

Comment: @Jack the `input` has only a margin-right, no margin-bottom.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I saw that.

Comment: Why don’t you explicitly set the height of `<p>`?

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPduw/).  I don't see the problem.

Comment: @igor because a `p` could span 2 rows

Comment: Can you show a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?  I put in your code, closed the CSS that was missing ";" on many of your lines, added a background-color to the <p> and measured on screen and it showed 23px with no problem.  My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tPduw/).

Comment: `;` is not mandatory at the end, i have posted the page in the post below.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the line-height of p to 19px or add a margin-bottom: -2px to the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/EWfyM/

```
p {
   line-height:23px; 
   vertical-align:top;
   margin:0 0 8px 0;
   padding:0;
   clear:both
}
input {
   margin:0 5px 0 0; 
   padding:0; 
   height:23px;
   margin-bottom: -2px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
   border: none; 
   background:none;
   vertical-align:text-bottom
}
label {
   vertical-align:top
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I use 19px; the p is still 26px high

Comment: @Stofken read the edit, I would go with adding the negative margin to the input.

Comment: a -5px margin-bottom indeed keeps the input 23px high and now the p is also 23px high; I don't think a negative margin is a particularly elegant solution, but it sure does the trick!
Any idea why the 5px ??

Comment: @Stofken no what browser are you having to use -5px in? In Chrome I am able to return a height of 23px with a -2px margin.  I am also not a fan of the stigma behind using negative margins, if there wasn't a situation where negative margins shouldn't be used then they wouldn't have been included :)

Comment: @Stofken also if my answer answers your question please check the check mark.

Comment: I am also using Chrome, but I need -5px

Comment: I've seen the screenshot, looks nice, however not in my page :(
I think it has something to do with the vertical-align, not padding or margin (as there is none).
Test page: (http://www.hostbasket.com/nl/hiddenfolder/add-server-step1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not answer your question of "Why?", but using firebug I was able to get your paragraph height to display as 23px by changing the height of your radio button.

This is the CSS I changed:

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
box-shadow: 0 0 0;
height: 18px;
margin: 0 5px 0 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Notice I changed your `height: 23px;` to `height: 18px`.  I could not find an answer online, but perhaps the radio button itself has some default height.

Comment: this is a solution, however i think the solution is the changed vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

Using display inline works:

(I've used inline css here)

```
<p style="display:inline;margin:0 0 0px 0;padding:0;clear:both;">
   <input type="radio" value="79" id="SQL:79" name="SQL" maxlength="300" style="display:inline;margin:0 0px 0 0; padding:0; height:19px;border:none; background:none;vertical-align:middle;position:relative;top:-2px;">
   <label for="SQL:79" style="display:inline;">Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express - 64 bit</label>
</p>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the p should remain a block level item, and when applying the inline, my p reduces to 13px!

Answer (score 0):

The p tag will get expanded as per the content size.
We have to specify the height for the p tag if we need.

Comment: This may cause problems in other areas of the site where specifying the line-height is sufficient. Modifications should be made to the inputs, not the p element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is modifed css (simplify :)):

```
p {
   line-height:23px; 
   vertical-align:top;
   margin:0 0 8px 0;
   padding:0;
   clear:both
}
input {
   margin:0; 
   padding:0; 
}
input[type="radio"] {
   border: none; 
   background:none;
}
label {
   vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

1. Setting the height of input[type=radio] cannot enlarge its visual
   shape. So I delete the height.
2. When the display of child element (input) is inline or inline-block,
   setting the line-height of parent element can align the child
   element center vertically. But you can also align the child element
   top or bottom vertically with vertical-align.

Comment: 1. input has no margin-bottom of 8px, where do you see that?
2. I don't understand, you're saying height doesn't work on input?
3. I know line-height can center vertically, that's why I applied it to the p, the child element was also aligned vertically, but the text-bottom caused the extra pixels

Comment: Sorry, I doesn't see. The height works on input but it doesn't change the **visual** size of input when the type of input is radio.So I think there is no need to set the height.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the vertical-align on the input[type=radio] from text-bottom to plain bottom/top